# Get the selected text on <p> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, text

Using jquery or pure javascript, is there a way to get the currently selected text of a `<p>` tag? I'm aware of [input.selectionStart](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#dom-textarea/input-selectionstart),  but it only exists on `<input>`.

Comment: Here is something worth to look at http://motyar.blogspot.com/2010/02/get-user-selected-text-with-jquery-and.html

Comment: Here also http://mark.koli.ch/2009/09/use-javascript-and-jquery-to-get-user-selected-text.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple solution. Works in chrome, safari, FF, and IE9+, but you will have to test on any other legacy browsers you may want to support. http://jsfiddle.net/YEu3k/1/

```
<p id="pText">here is some text</p>

<script>
    document.getElementById('pText').onmouseup = function(){
        var sel = window.getSelection(), range;
        if (sel.getRangeAt) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            alert(range);
        }
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use https://github.com/madapaja/jquery.selection

selection range is different behavior in each browsers. this plugin make commonly interfaces to selection range.